# Add text over a polyline android google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, polyline

I want to achieve something like this in android using google maps polylines :
[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: I have all kinds of ideas now.  But no time to implement them.  Check out this project on github  https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils code that will caclculate the bearing between two points maybe you can use that to write along the polyline.  Also it looks like from the picture your not using the end point of each polyline as the startpoint of the next polyline.